# Windows Skips Grub after cmd

Tags: boot, grub2

I used the command `BootRec.exe /fixmbr` thinking I could get the Windows boot manager instead of Grub.

Now it just skips Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Windows boot manager won't recognise Ubuntu if you ran that command. Simplest fix is to run your Ubuntu install disk again - it may recognise the old install, but worst case you may just need to reinstall Ubuntu.